# No validation for tampered URL for flag history

Tags: bug, flag-history

These are the current group flags:

- Post Flags - this includes NAA, VLQ, other flags
- Comment Flags - all comment flag types - too chatty, not constructive, obsolete, *rude or offensive*, etc.
- Spam Flags
- Offensive Flags

In my flagging history I only have *Post Flags* and *Comment flags*. Clicking on post flags adds `group=1` querystring to the URL, respectively `group=4` for comment flags.

Curious as I am, I wanted to see what `group=2` and `group=3` are (and that's how I knew about spam and offensive flags).

The bugs?

- I see empty pages for `group=2` and `group=3`. Obviously, since I don't have any.
- I see "Oops! Something bad happened!" for any other value (like [`group=5`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3233388?group=5))

I think these requests should be validated and respond appropriately.

Comment: Same *Oops! Something bad happened* with `status=10` querystring

Comment: So, do you consider the empty pages a "bug"? Why?

Comment: Also, why is it a bug that an invalid url returns a error page?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Because the error page in question is an ASP.NET fatal error that's not supposed to be encountered under normal circumstances. Most of the validation errors on the site don't result in "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" but some other message - such as a fake 404 if you follow the group=5 link in the question for example.

Comment: @Cerbrus **(1)** Search query returning 0 results usually give a "no results" message. The same principle applies here **(2)** It's an unhandled server error - it's a bug. By SO standards, you should be redirected to the flags history with no querystring

Comment: Interestingly, `?group=1000` just shows me my flags. What's so special about `5` that causes it to throw an error?

Comment: In fact, ___any___ invalid group _below_ `256` (so `5`-`255`) throws that error. `256+` is just ignored. (Gee, is the `group` an 8-bit value?)

Comment: @Cerbrus it's absolutely possible that it's a byte value. They are quite common in the codebase.

Comment: Meh, not seeing any point of doing anything about this if the only "benefit" is that people that tamper with the URL see a different type of error response.

Comment: @MartinSmith it’s an invitation to see what else is not vaidated

Comment: Well presumably it is "validated" in some sense as when you pass an invalid value you get an error. This might just be a default on a case statement that throws an error saying "no such group"

Comment: And it is not a bug to show you empty pages for spam flags and offensive flags when you haven't raised any. The existence of these flag types is not a secret and you certainly could raise these flags if you wanted to. The flag history page doesnt provide any links to these pages if not relevant but that doesn't mean you are not permitted to visit them and bask in their emptiness.

Comment: @MartinSmith are you trying to convince yourself that this is as intended?

Comment: No. Are you trying to convince yourself that you've perpetrated some amazing hack revealing the hitherto unknown existence of spam and offensive flags?

Comment: @MartinSmith  nope. I found a bug, I reported it. It IS a bug. If you believe it’s not, perhaps this is not your area of expertise, and that’s ok, but please don’t act like I’m factually incorrect, because you are wrong.

Comment: Worth noting that if the user ID is one that you can't access (any user besides yourself for normal users), you just get SO's waffle keyboard 404.

Comment: @Cerbrus "Oops something bad" is a 500 error. This should clearly be a 4xx error of some kind. But I think this might be a waste of time to fix. Definitely very low priority.